# How to terminate all loop in python

Tags: python

I'm still super beginner in learning python right now and english is not my native language .I hope there is someone can answer my problem. My concern is how can I end all the loop when enter 'e'. I try to modify the code so that it exit all the loop when enter 'e' but the when I also enter 'm' , it also same when enter 'e' instead I want to return back to the menu loop when I enter 'm'. Thank you. Code below

```
def A():
  print("a")
def B():
  print("B")
def Menu():
  print("Menu")
  print("1.A")
  print("2.B")
while True:
  Menu()
  while True:
    option = input("Choose a or b")
    if option == 'a':
      A()
      break
    elif option == 'b':
      B()
      break
    else:
      print("Choose 'a' or 'b' only")
  while True:
    repeat = input("'m' or 'e'")
    if repeat != 'e' and repeat != 'm':
      print("Choose 'm' or 'e' only'")
    if repeat == 'm':
      break
    if repeat == 'e':
      break
  break
```

Comment: Put everything into a function and `return`.

Answer (score 0):

I undestand your problem **so** I'll give you the only clean solution:

```
while True: # A loop
    while True: # B loop
        ...
        # Now from here...
# ...you want to go here?
```

If you want to exit both B and A loop from inside B loop, there's only one clean way:

```
def foo():
    while True:
        while True:
            ...
            return # Will end both loops
```

Put the whole thing into a function and replace the "double `break`" with `return`.

---

There's an other solution that I would nickname "boolean label solution" which works in most cases but it's less clean so I will just give you a clue.

```
flag = true
while flag:
    while True:
        if (condition_to_exit):
            flag = false
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just wish to exit the program after exiting the loops, just use the `exit()` function:

```py
while True:
    ...
    while True:
        ...
        exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating functions for the user input, this way your code will be cleaner and easier to understand.

Look how clean the main loop looks now, it's very clear what it does:

- Executes the Menu function
- Lets the user choose whether to execute A or B
- Asks user to input "m" or "e"
- If user inputs "e" it breaks the loop

That's the steps the main loop has to do, so that's all the code that should be there. Code for checking if the user inputs the right options is not the main loop business, it should be inside a function.

This way you delegate tasks and responsibilities to different parts of the code, which for bigger projects it might not be you who programs them.

The code than be further improved and refactored, for example you might want to use dictionaries for the options of your menu. So each key is an option and the value is the function to be executed. This way your `Menu()` would be just a loop iterating over the dictionary to display the options and then executing the associated function.

Also you might want to take a look at classes, since all this will fit better encapsulated inside a class.

But first and most important: Keep your code clean, self descriptive and organized.

```
def A():
    print("a")

def B():
    print("B")

def Menu():
    print("Menu")
    print("1.A")
    print("2.B")

def ExecuteAorB():
    while True:
        option = input("Choose a or b")
        if option == 'a':
            A()
            break
        elif option == 'b':
            B()
            break
        else:
          print("Choose 'a' or 'b' only")

def AskUserMorE():
    while True:
        repeat = input("'m' or 'e'")
        if repeat not in ('e', 'm'):
            print("Choose 'm' or 'e' only'")
        else:
            return repeat
    

while True:
    Menu()
    ExecuteAorB()
    userInput = AskUserMorE()
    if userInput == 'e':
        break
```